# Should "diplomacy" and "interspecies-diplomacy" tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I find it really strange that we used [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) 7 times but [diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomacy) only once.

I think someone should suggest  [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) as a synonym to [diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomacy). Or maybe we should just use diplomacy, it's all the same thing.

I don't have enough rep to suggest the synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the tags.

- I replaced [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) with [communication](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) for
  2 of them.
- I replaced [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) with [communication](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) and
  added [diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomacy) for 1 them.
- I replaced [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) with [sociology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociology) for 1 of
  them.
- I deleted the tag for 3 of them because it was not required.

[interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) Has fallen into oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they're synonyms, but I also don't think [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) needs its own tag. [inter-species](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inter-species) maybe, then you could pair it with [diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomacy) when you're specifically talking about governments.

Google definition of diplomacy: `the profession, activity, or skill of managing international relations, typically by a country's representatives abroad.`

I don't really think (for example) [Culture shock… Alien Social Activities](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5200/culture-shock-alien-social-activities) should count as a question about diplomacy, but it certainly has a lot to do with interspecies interactions.

I guess what I'm saying is that we keep [diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomacy), but change [interspecies-diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-diplomacy) to just [inter-species](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inter-species). Not sure how this is done, but I think it would help.

Comment: I think your conception of diplomacy is too narrow. You forgot to mention the ''usually refer to...''. Of course they are unlikely to mention diplomacy with extraterrestrial worlds since we don't have an embassy there yet. But you are also right, most of these questions aren't about diplomacy.

Comment: @Vincent I don't understand what you mean (except that I'm right :D). I understand diplomacy to deal with higher-level interaction between societies like with governments and commerce, whereas my proposed interspecies tag would deal with more low-level interactions, such as interspecies coworkers or neighbors.

Comment: The easiest way to change a tag with so few uses is to just manually edit the questions involved. Note that this bumps them to the top of the front page; it is acceptable in this case *simply because* there are so few of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can just use [diplomacy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomacy).  I don't think we need a synonym; if somebody types "interspecies-diplomacy" he'll get a match on "diplomacy", and if he means some *other* interspecies concern (e.g. biology) he won't want that.  So I'm not sure a synonym actually helps here.